# Pack list of ints in Python

Tags: python, struct

I have got a list that I am packing as bytes using `struct` module in Python. Here is my list:

> [39, 39, 126, 126, 256, 258, 260, 259, 257, 126]

I am packing my list as:

```
encoded = struct.pack(">{}H".format(len(list)), *list)
```

where I pass number of elements in list as a format.

Now, I need to unpack the packed struct. For that I will need a format where I again pass number of elements. For now I am doing it like so:

```
struct.unpack(">{}H".format(10), encoded)
```

However, I can't pass it as a simple parameter to function `format` because that struct is then written to file that I am using for compressing image. How can I add a number of elements to file, and unpack it after?

P.S. I would like to get that `10` (in unpacking) from file itself that is packed as bytes.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. How is it relevant that the struct is written to a compressed file? What's that about passing something as a parameter to a function? Which part of your code doesn't work as intended?

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: If you want to read the number 10 from the file, then you have to write it into the file first.

Comment: I know. But how? That is my question. How to write it as one more chunk of bytes, in addition to that already packed struct.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to tell me that you know how to write a list of 10 numbers into the file, but you don't know how to do the same thing with a single number?

Comment: No, I want for example add that 10 as bytes to the file (to the packed struct). But I don't know how to convert that 10 to bytes, and concat it to that packed list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach of adding that [number of elements] to the file:

```
file.write(len(compressed_list).to_bytes(3,'big'))
```

I allocate 3 bytes of memory for the length of `compressed_list`, convert it to bytes, and add it to the beginning of the file. Further, write other left parts.

---

Next, when I need that number, I get it from the file like so:

```
sz = int.from_bytes(encoded[0:3],'big')
```

which means that I take first three bytes from byte array read from the file, and typecast that bytes to int.

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Form what I understood from the comments and questions. Maybe this will be helpful.

```
import struct
data = [39, 39, 126, 126, 256, 258, 260, 259, 257, 126]

encoded = struct.pack(">{}H".format(len(data)), *data)
tmp = struct.pack(">H", len(data))
encoded = tmp + encoded #appending at the start
begin = 2
try:
    size = struct.unpack(">H", encoded[0:begin])[0]
    print(size)
    print(struct.unpack(">{}H".format(size), encoded[begin:]))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I guess this will work. I have implemented some kind of similar solution that I will post later.

Comment: `">{}H".format(1)` is redundant. Just use `">H"` instead.

Comment: Yes, updated the answer. I was trying the same thing with multidimensional list. There I needed to prepend more data to the binary. It was copy and paste :) . Thanks.